# i am tryin to create a method decorator in angular but this error shows up

Tags: angular, typescript, decorator

```
export class IceCreamComponent {
  @Emoji()
  flavor = 'vanilla';
}


// Property Decorator
function Emoji() {
  return function(target: Object, key: string | symbol) {

    let val = target[key];

    const getter = () =>  {
        return val;
    };
    const setter = (next:any) => {
        console.log('updating flavor...');
        val = ` ${next} `;
    };

    Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
      get: getter,
      set: setter,
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
    });

  };
}
```

i got error:

> error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression
> of type 'string | symbol' can't be used to index type 'Object'.   No
> index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type
> 'Object'.
>
> 11     let val = target[key];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is that `string` can't be used to index the type of `Object` because the object type is just an empty object by default. Therefore it isn't possible to use a string type to index `{}`.
You can tell Angular what type of Object that you are expecting by giving its type like this

```js
let val = (key: string) => (target: Record<string, any>) => target[key];
```

Now the error should disappear as we are telling the compiler that `target` will be a collection of `string/value` i.e. in our case `(string/any)` pairs.

Answer (score 1):

```
let val = (<any>target)[key];
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.